# Thread safety with heap-allocated memory

Tags: c++, thread-safety, heap-memory, stack-memory

I was reading this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety

Is the following function thread-safe?

```
void foo(int y){
    int * x = new int[50];
    /*...do some stuff with the allocated memory...*/
    delete [] x;
}
```

In the article it says that to be thread-safe you can only use variables from the stack. Really? Why? Wouldn't subsequent calls of the above function allocate memory elsewhere?

Edit: Ah. Looks like I misread this part of the article:

> A subroutine is reentrant, and thus thread-safe, if
>
> - the only variables it uses are from the stack

(I took it to mean

> A subroutine is reentrant, and thus thread-safe, if **and only if**
>
> - the only variables it uses are from the stack

, which according to the answers below, is not the case)

Comment: Use `delete[]` for arrays not `delete`

Comment: @Brian: Woops - thanks. I added the array part in after I had already typed the function out, in order to make it extra clear that I was allocating memory dynamically, but forgot to add the []'s. +1 :)

Comment: It's amazing to see the spreading usage of wikipedia as THE reference for programming concepts :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are coding in an environment that supports multi-threading, then you can be pretty sure `new` is thread safe.

Although the memory is on the heap, the pointer to it is on the stack. Only your thread has the pointer to this memory, and so there is no risk of concurrent modification - no other thread knows where the memory is to modify it.

You would only get a problem with thread safety if you were to pass this pointer to another thread that would then concurrently modify this memory at the same time as your original (or another) thread.

Comment: Thanks. Tough choice between your answer and Peter's, but your helpful hint at the end was relevant, while his was about vectors :)

Comment: @mdma True but is it possible to allocate memory on the heap and by random bad chance it overlaps another thread's heap memory?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't say you can only use stack variables, it says that using heap variables "suggests the need for careful examination to see if it is unsafe".

`new` and `delete` are normally implemented in a threadsafe way (not sure that the standard guarantees that though) so your code above will probably be fine.

Plus usual recommendations of using `std::vector` instead of manually allocating an array, but I assume you only provided that as an example :)

Comment: I recall operating in an environment where they weren't. Now *that* was hairy.

Comment: It's fortunate that you can override them then :)

Answer (score 1):

new and delete may or may not be thread safe.  They probably are, but that is implementation-dependent.  See:
[C++ new operator thread safety in linux and gcc 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796099/c-new-operator-thread-safety-in-linux-and-gcc-4)

To be thread safe, a function must either use stack variables or synchronize its access to other resources with other threads.  As long as separate calls to new allocate different space on the heap when called from different threads, you should be fine.