# C++ deleting object, does it lock?

Tags: c++, thread-safety, lock-free

Using C++, when I create a new object, then 'new' keyword do some locks (since it does some memory allocation, etc). So, I cannot use it directly in a lock-free software.

However, does the 'delete' keyword create any kind of lock?

I'm still using C++98, I think it will work in the same way in C++11;

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845980/thread-safety-with-heap-allocated-memory

Comment: I don't think it will, delete calls destructor and simply disregard chunk of memory it once instantiated. waiting for someone to expand too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for locks in `new` is, as you say, the memory allocation. If the allocation requires a lock, it is very likely, at least under some circumstances, that the corresponding de-allocation also requires locks. It is of course possible that the de-allocation is lockless, even if allocation requires locks.

Note that `delete` itself doesn't do locking (neither does `new`), it is the underlying primitive that does. So if you have a lock-less allocator, then there should be no issues using `new` and `delete`. [Presuming the constructor and destructor are lock-less, of course].

Note that placement forms `new` and `delete` shouldn't be locking.

Avoiding `new` and `delete` (or at least allocations) probably also restricts a huge amount of what you can do. All containers except `std::array` (in C++11) will perform allocations, for example, so no `std::vector`, `std::string`, `std::map`, etc. Many constructors perform allocations for the object created. And of course, there may be locks in other functions than `new` and `delete` - I/O functions often have locks to prevent completely garbled output (but not necessarily guaranteeing the whole output to NOT be garbled, either). Pretty much anything that uses a common shared resource is likely to have locks at some level, be that inside the OS or at the user-mode level.

The C++ standard doesn't really say anything in this regard, it is an implementation detail.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth explanation :)

Comment: The whole program doesn't have to be lockless.  You could use a `std::vector` as long as you aren't growing it in the "hot" part of your code.  And even if each thread is growing its own `std::vector`, it grows exponentially so the contention from different threads competing for the allocator lock should be very infrequent unless they all grow / shrink in lock-step.  (So every thread's `vector` is the same size and would all re-alloc at the same time.)  Anyway, `operator []` on `vector` is fine.  (You can't make a shared `std::vector`, and don't consider `atomic<vector<int>>`, that's slow.)

Comment: Peter, the problem is I'm coding an VST plugin, which audio thread need to be 100% lock-free. The interface may have locks

Answer (score 1):

The C++98 *standard* has no concept of multithreading. It is to the latitude of the implementation to implement thread safety. Also, the standard indicates only how should the program *behave*.

For example, there are implementations available which don't actually release memory to the OS when calling `delete`.

This being said, the answer for C++98 is that it might not lock. But it is implementation independent.

In C++11, things are quite different, since the standard introduces the concept of multithreading.