# new and delete handles multithreading issues

Tags: c++, multithreading, new-operator

I am reading a book [Efficient C++: Performance Programming Techniques](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201379503) Authors is saying following regarding global new and delete operators:

> They manage memory in the process context, and since a process may
>   spawn multiple threads, `new()` and `delete()` must be able to operate in
>   a multithreaded environment. In addition, the size of memory requests
>   may vary from one request to the next.

in *Chapter 6. Single-Threaded Memory Pooling*.

Is this true? I thought C++ does not have a notion of a *Multi-threading environment*, programmer need to handle is by using some means of mutual exclusion.

Comment: And your question?  How this would be implemented?

Comment: @trojanfoe Book further provides implementation of memory allocation with single and multi thread supports, but when I tried his first approach it was failing on Visual Studio compiler, so I got a doubt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will depend on implementation. For example, Visual C++ runtime had both a single-threaded and a multithreaded version of heap in earlier version, but starting with Visual C++ 2005 it only has a multithreaded version. [This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) has a nice summary table.

When a multithreaded heap is used calls to memory allocation and deallocation are thread-safe at expense of additional overhead.

Answer (score 3):

C++ (C++03 standard) doesn't talk about multi-threading. However most of the platforms support thread-safe `new/malloc`. Here is a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796099/c-new-operator-thread-safety-in-linux-and-gcc-4) discussing same kind of question.

In C++11, the threads are introduced.

Comment: +1 for the difference between the Standard and the practical applications. C and C++ have been multithreaded for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

As of C++11 (which has the concept of a data race) the standard guarantees that `new/delete`, `calloc/malloc/realloc/free`will occur in a single total order.

From n3690 18.6.1.4:

> For purposes of determining the existence of data races, the library versions of operator new, user replacement
>   versions of global operator new, the C standard library functions calloc and malloc, the library
>   versions of operator delete, user replacement versions of operator delete, the C standard library function
>   free, and the C standard library function realloc shall not introduce a data race (17.6.5.9). Calls to
>   these functions that allocate or deallocate a particular unit of storage shall occur in a single total order, and
>   each such deallocation call shall happen before (1.10) the next allocation (if any) in this order.

I could not find any such guarantees in previous versions of the standard, but (like others have said) I believe most implementations provide multi-threading support for memory allocation.